# How To Handle GDI Resource Leak

Tags: visual-c++, gdi

In my application I am getting DC using GetDC and I am also releasing that DC using ReleaseDC.

But when I am profiling my application with VTune, it is showing a GDIResource Leak at GetDC.

```
m_hdc = ::GetDC(hWndDisplay[frameIndex]);
::SetStretchBltMode(m_hdc,STRETCH_DELETESCANS);
::StretchDIBits(m_hdc,0,0,IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT,0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight,rgbavpg,pTempBmpInfo,DIB_RGB_COLORS,SRCCOPY);
::ReleaseDC(hWndDisplay[frameIndex],m_hdc);
```

---

The following is relevant code: m_hdc id defined globally as  HDC m_hdc;

```
void Display(unsigned char *rgbavpg,unsigned long imageSize, unsigned int imageWidth, unsigned int imageHeight, unsigned int frameIndex)
{

PBITMAPINFO pTempBmpInfo = NULL;
DWORD timespan;
int temp;

if ((IMAGE_WIDTH==imageWidth)&&(IMAGE_HEIGHT==imageHeight))
{
    frameNum++ ;
}
timespan = 1000/15;
DWORD diff = GetTickCount() - tickes[frameIndex];//lvm4;
tickes[frameIndex]=GetTickCount();
if (g_threadMarkedForStop[frameIndex] == TRUE ) 
{        
    return;
}
if(diff < timespan)
    { 
            Sleep(diff);
    }
if (FALSE == ::IsWindow(hWndDisplay[frameIndex])) 
{
    g_threadMarkedForStop[frameIndex] = TRUE
    return;
}

pTempBmpInfo = &m_bmpinfo[frameIndex];
if(pTempBmpInfo != NULL)
{
    pTempBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biWidth= imageWidth ;
    pTempBmpInfo->bmiHeader.biHeight= imageHeight;
}
else 
{
    g_threadMarkedForStop[frameIndex] = TRUE;

    return;
}
m_hdc = ::GetDC(hWndDisplay[frameIndex]);
     ::SetStretchBltMode(m_hdc,STRETCH_DELETESCANS);

if (true == fullscreen)                ::StretchDIBits(m_hdc,0,0,510,320,0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight,rgbavpg,pTempBmpInfo,DIB_RGB_COLORS,SRCCOPY);
else
{       ::StretchDIBits(m_hdc,0,0,IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT,0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight,rgbavpg,pTempBmpInfo,DIB_RGB_COLORS,SRCCOPY);
    //::SetDIBitsToDevice(m_hdc,0,0,IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT,0,0,0,imageHeight,rgbavpg,pTempBmpInfo,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
}
::ReleaseDC(hWndDisplay[frameIndex],m_hdc);
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: There's no obvious leak in that snippet.  Why is m_hdc a member of your class?  That can't be right.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well m_hdc is the handle of type HDC defined globally.  Could you please elaborate why you think this cannot be right?

Comment: I'm assuming that Hans' point was that dc's should be used and disposed-of as soon as you don't need them anymore. They're memory/resource consuming, bmp's that are selected into them can't be deleted, so it's generally wrong practice to keep them lying around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite using a member variable m_hdc and not using a local variable this code by itself looks good.

Do you see VTune marking that leak every time or only sometimes?

When I see your call to IsWindow() and the variable name g_threadMarkedForStop I wonder if you are doing multithreading. Could it be that you sometimes destroy the window while being between GetDC and ReleaseDC?

Comment: Thanks for reply...
Actually my application display one or more video thumbnails by decoding through codec frame by frame.VTune is showing no leak to display one video thumbnails but for more then one video thumbnails it is showing GDIResource leak at m_hdc = ::GetDC(hWndDisplay[frameIndex]); even I am releasing it as you can see I have used ReleaseDC. Yes I have done multithreading to display one or more thumbnails. And I am not destroying window in between GetDC and ReleaseDC. Is there any other possible way to release DC? Please reply soon.

Thanks & Regards
Mayank

Comment: In this case I would 1) change m_hdc to a local variable to be sure you do not change m_hdc from anywhere and 2) check the return value of ReleaseDC to be sure Windows really released the DC. If VTune is still complaining after these two changes you might ignore the VTune error message.

Comment: Thank You Werner,

My problem is solved now.Now I have declared m_hdc locally and it's working.But still I want to ask you that what was the reason of GDIResource leak when I was declared Globally?
Again thank you very much....

Comment: I don't know. Did you use m_hdc anywhere else or overwrite it unintentionally? If not, then the only reason I could think about is that you called Display() in parallel from two threads (maybe for different frameIndex) and while the one thread just set m_hdc and StretchDIBits the other thread overwrote m_hdc thus leading to the first DC not being released and the second DC being released twice.

Comment: thank you for your Reply.No I am not using m_hdc anywhere else or overwriting it. Yes I think you are right it was releasing 2nd DC two time and 1st one was not released do it was showing GDIResource leak.
Thank You & Regards

Mayank...